# webmatrix list of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, webmatrix

List of keyboard shortcuts supported by Microsoft webmatrix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Official list from Microsoft here:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/webmatrix-keyboard-shortcut-guide

[image: WebMatrix Shortcut Keys]

Also, you can use the Alt key to display top level key tips. The top level key tips are show below:

[image: WebMatrix Top Level Key Tips]

Then, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus a top level key (such as <kbd>H</kbd> for Home as shown above) to show all of the keys that can be used on that tab. Use the displayed key value to access the related functionality.

[image: WebMatrix Ribbon Tab Keys]

For instance, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> then <kbd>T</kbd> will allow you to print.

Comment: Keyboard assignments are defined in the following text file: C:\program files\Microsoft WebMatrix\config\hotkeys.txt

Comment: For 64-bit Windows: %PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Microsoft WebMatrix\config\hotkeys.txt

Answer (score 4):

Just for those who happen upon this post, please check out the up to date list here:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/webmatrix-keyboard-shortcut-guide

Answer (score 2):

Here are some additional ones that work inside the editor. Mind these are in an internal format that maps hotkeys to command codes. Its fairly readable though.

If you save this file in the WebMatrix config folder (typically c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\Config), the editor will pick up modifications you make to this file. *** Use at your own risk ***

```
None;Right;RIGHT
None;Left;LEFT
None;Up;UP
None;Down;DOWN
None;PageUp;PAGEUP
None;Next;PAGEDN
None;Home;HOME
None;End;END
None;Escape;CANCEL
None;Delete;DELETE
None;Back;BACKSPACE
None;Insert;INSERT
None;Return;RETURN
None;Tab;TAB
Shift;Back;BACKSPACE
Shift;Right;RIGHT_EXT
Shift;Left;LEFT_EXT
Shift;Up;UP_EXT
Shift;Down;DOWN_EXT
Shift;Home;HOME_EXT
Shift;End;END_EXT
Shift;PageUp;PAGEUP_EXT
Shift;Next;PAGEDN_EXT
Shift;Tab;BACKTAB
Shift;Return;RETURN
Alt, Shift;Right;RIGHT_EXT
Alt, Shift;Left;LEFT_EXT
Alt, Shift;Up;UP_EXT
Alt, Shift;Down;DOWN_EXT
Alt, Shift;Home;HOME_EXT
Alt, Shift;End;END_EXT
Control, Shift;Right;CTLMOVERIGHT
Control, Shift;Left;CTLMOVELEFT
Control, Shift;Home;TOPLINE_EXT
Control, Shift;End;BOTTOMLINE_EXT
Control, Shift;L;DELETELINE
Control, Shift;Oem6;GOTOBRACE_EXT
Control, Shift;Space;PARAMINFO
Control, Shift;P;SELUPCASE
Control, Shift;W;SELLOWCASE
Control;Space;COMPLETEWORD
Control;J;SHOWMEMBERLIST
Control;Back;DELETEWORDLEFT
Control;Delete;DELETEWORDRIGHT
Control;A;SELECTALL
Control;Right;WORDNEXT
Control;Left;WORDPREV
Control;Home;TOPLINE
Control;End;BOTTOMLINE
Control;Up;SCROLLUP
Control;Down;SCROLLDN
Control;C;COPY
Control;X;CUT
Control;V;PASTE
Control;Z;UNDO
Control;Y;REDO
Control;OemPlus;ZOOMIN
Control;Add;ZOOMIN
Control;OemMinus;ZOOMOUT
Control;Subtract;ZOOMOUT
Control;D0;ZOOM1X
Control;NumPad0;ZOOM1X
Control;Oem6;GOTOBRACE
Control;L;CUTLINE
Control;T;TRANSPOSECHAR
Control,Control;K,D;FORMATDOCUMENT
Control,Control;K,F;FORMATSELECTION
Control,Control;K,I;QUICKINFO
Control,Control;K,C;COMMENT_BLOCK
Control,Control;K,U;UNCOMMENT_BLOCK
Control,Control;M,M;OUTLN_TOGGLE_ALL
Control,Control;M,U;OUTLN_TOGGLE_CURRENT
Control,Control;M,O;OUTLN_COLLAPSE_TO_DEF
Control,Control;M,P;OUTLN_STOP_HIDING_ALL
Control,Control;M,S;OUTLN_START_AUTOHIDING
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> moves a letter one step to the left?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> search in file (direction down)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> find

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> go to line

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> replace

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> new file

Answer (score 0):

To view the current file in the browser instead of the site root.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

As the Webmatrix 2 'Run' button opens the root index html file.